# Generate in Python combinations of n elements of a list taken from r in r and check for constraint satisfaction

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools, combinatorics

Suppose we have the following list representing candidate IDs:

```
candidates = list(range(1,37))
```

I would like to generate, in an affordable computational time, a list containing 6 list of tuples, that are the combinations of these 36 candidates taken 6 by 6, with no candidate matching any other candidate in any of the previous lists.

```
resul = []
```

Let's consider an example. The first valid combination can be obtained in the simplest way:

```
ex1 = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), (13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18), 
(19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24), (25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30), (31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36)]
```

So, **ex1** can be appended to the list:

```
resul.append(ex1)
```

Now I would like to start generating combinations, for example **ex2** would be a valid combination, since no elements are not repeated in each tuple of the list of tuples of **resul**:

```
ex2 = [(1, 8, 18, 23, 28, 33), (3, 7, 14, 24, 29, 34), (4, 9, 13, 20, 30, 35),
(5, 10, 15, 19, 26, 36), (6, 11, 16, 21, 25, 32), (2, 12, 17, 22, 27, 31)]
```

So, **ex2** can be appended too:

```
resul.append(ex2)
```

Another case, **ex3**, couldn't be appended, since 1 and 5 are already together in the first tuple of the first element of the list (ex1):

```
ex3 = [(1, 12, 5, 25, 30, 35), ..., ..., ..., ..., ...]
```

So, as I mentioned, I would like to get **just 6 elements** that meet the above constraints, and for this I would like to know how to generate these combinations of 36 elements taken 6 by 6 and check the satisfaction of the constraints.

Comment: So, what you mean is, you don't want two items in the same 6-tuple if they were in a previous 6-tuple.  Is that right?

Comment: I'm not convinced that it possible to generate more than two.

Comment: OK, I can generate 3, but apparently not any more.

Comment: Hello Tim yes exactly don't want two items in the same 6-tuple if they were in a previous 6-tuple. Can you please post the code? It probably will need much much time to get the 4th combination, and increasing exponentially… Thanks

Comment: I have to say that in the worst case scenario where no more than 3 combinations are found, the 4th, 5th and 6th may contain as few matches as possible. That could become accepted as a solution

Answer (score 0):

I can generate 3.  We have the sequential original, then we basically transpose that, then we start picking from the rows with an offset.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

x = np.arange(1,37,dtype=int).reshape((6,6))
print(x)

def pick(inx,n):
    xx = np.zeros((6,6),dtype=int)
    for y in range(6):
        for x in range(6):
            xx[y][x] = inx[x][(y+x*n)%6]
    return xx

def pairs(p,x):
    for row in x:
        row = set((itertools.combinations(row,2)))
        if p.intersection(row):
            print("BAD:", p.intersection(row))
        else:
            p |= row

uniquepairs = set()
pairs(uniquepairs, x)

for n in (0,1,2,3,4):
    print("Attempting offset of", n)
    nxt = pick(x,n)
    print(nxt)
    pairs(uniquepairs,nxt)
```

That gives:

```
[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
 [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]
 [13 14 15 16 17 18]
 [19 20 21 22 23 24]
 [25 26 27 28 29 30]
 [31 32 33 34 35 36]]
Attempting offset of 0
[[ 1  7 13 19 25 31]
 [ 2  8 14 20 26 32]
 [ 3  9 15 21 27 33]
 [ 4 10 16 22 28 34]
 [ 5 11 17 23 29 35]
 [ 6 12 18 24 30 36]]
Attempting offset of 1
[[ 1  8 15 22 29 36]
 [ 2  9 16 23 30 31]
 [ 3 10 17 24 25 32]
 [ 4 11 18 19 26 33]
 [ 5 12 13 20 27 34]
 [ 6  7 14 21 28 35]]
```

After that, any other offset produces duplicates.

Comment: Hello Tim. As I told you in the other answer section, it is possible to accept 4th, 5th and 6th as long as they are the cases that "minimize" the number of duplicates. How would you go about detecting the best possible combination in this scenario? Thank you very much for everything

Comment: The 4th one has 3 conflicts in each line, out of 15 combinations.  The 5th and 6th have 9 conflicts in each line, out of 15 combinations.  My script above generates all 6, I just didn't include the others in my sample output.